# Autocorrelation problem with "time series" data

Tags: regression, time-series, python, autocorrelation

[image]I have some data in python that I plan to run a linear regression on but first I tested the assumptions of linear regression. When it came to autocorrelation my Durbin Watson statistic was 0.14 which indicates positive autocorrelation. The job id is not the same, the first 15 or so are 20000 but after that, it will go to 20001 and the percent complete will reset making a lot of 'mini time series.' Everything I've tried looking up thus far assumes one giant time series which I don't have so I have no idea how to deal with this autocorrelation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually have a sample of the data that you could post? That would really help.

Comment: @krishnab Done, to clarify, not all of the JOB id's are 20000, those are just the first 15 or so

Comment: Okay, so usually to reduce autocorrelation you will take lags of a variable instead of the variable itself. So for a given ID, you have the june and july observations. Instead of regressing on the value in june and in july, you would regress on the differences in X and Y. For example $ Y(t) - Y(t-1) = a + b(X(t) - X(t-1))$. You can add additional lags if the autocorrelation last past the first lag. Do the common IDs matter, meaning is there any similarity between jobs with the same id?

Comment: Yes, the ID's are the same means they are the same job just at different points in time, the goal is to take a random snapshot of jobs in current time no matter their % completion and predict the lowest profit. So what transformation would need to be done specifically to get the differences? For every variable such as Over under, Final expected, should i be taking the difference between the row under it and it's row if they are the same ID?

Comment: you might want to try something as simple as the auto.arima() function in R. If you look at the Hyndman book https://otexts.com/fpp3/ , chapter 9 is about the type of models you are interested in. You can use that function to automatically do the transformations and stuff for you. That might be the easiest way to go, otherwise you might get caught up in a lot of technical discussions. That function will determine the appropriate number of lags that you need. You just need to filter your series by the ID and then you can predict forward the profits.